# Группа уникальных повторяющихся значений (что? да) Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица вида

| ID | HIGH | LOW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id1 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |

Как мне создать запрос в oracle sql (sqldeveloper, если важно), который отфильтрует **только** те записи, где в HIGH и LOW всё по нулям для каждого отдельного ID (для примера как в ID2 - там в каждой строке везде нули, а в ID1 только в одной - он в выборку попадать не должен)

Уже всю голову сломал, как запрос написать, чтобы выцепить подобные ID, где во всех вхождениях HIGH и LOW были нули (т.е. даже если в одной строчке где-то будет 1, то ID должен отвалится и в выборку не попасть). Проблема (для меня) в том, что в первом столбце получается много уникальных, но повторяющихся ID, поэтому дистинкт и тому подобное там нельзя использовать...или?

Comment: сгруппируйте по id и сумму max(high)+max(low) сравните с 0

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5bc44/8

Comment: Спасибо! Обнаружил еще, что в HIGH и LOW есть значения NULL. Как быть, если нужно вытащить ID'шники, чтобы во всех HIGH и LOW были только NULL-значения?

Comment: Это уже сложнее. Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, потому что местные ответы не годятся. Но тем не менее, можете  принять тот, который вы считаете правильным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, как-то так:

```
select id from high_and_low
group by id
having sum(high + low) = 0
```

По поводу одних `NULL` должно работать такое, просто делаем из `NULL` нули, а из остального единицы и проверяем в итоге тоже самое:

```
select id from high_and_low
group by id
having sum(NVL2(high, 1, 0) + NVL2(low, 1, 0)) = 0
```

Comment: достаточно `sum(high) + sum(low) = 0`

Comment: @splash58 Ну ладно, убедили )

Comment: а вот так  `sum(high+low) = 0` не работает :) ?

Comment: Спасибо! Продублирую сюда тоже, на всякий. Обнаружил еще, что в HIGH и LOW есть значения NULL. Как быть, если нужно вытащить ID'шники, чтобы во всех HIGH и LOW были только NULL-значения?

Comment: @lavand0 Добавил в ответ этот вариант

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так

```
select id from table t 
where t.HIGH = 0 and t.LOW = 0
minus
select id from table t 
where t.HIGH <> 0 or t.LOW <> 0
```