# Как правильно отфильтровать значения NULL по одному сложному (для меня) условию?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужна ваша помощь. Есть таблица вида

| ID | HIGH | LOW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | '1' | (null) |
| id1 | '1' | (null) |
| id1 | (null) | (null) |
| id2 | (null) | (null) |
| id2 | (null) | (null) |
| id2 | (null) | (null) |
| id2 | (null) | (null) |
| id2 | (null) | (null) |

Каким запросом можно отфильтровать столбец ID, чтобы туда попали только те ID, для которых во всех строках значения HIGH и LOW равны NULL (Поля HIWH и LOW являются типом VARCHAR2, не числом).

Т.е. для ID1, несмотря на то, что одна строка попадает под условие, не должен попасть в выборку, т.к. имеет строки не подходящие по условия. А вот ID2 - должен, т.к. у него во всех строках HIGH и LOW значения NULL.

Comment: [Как тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454331/%d0%93%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0-oracle-sql) а для проверки на null используйте либо not null, либо функцию nvl()

Comment: Я так понял, что в первом Where я укажу HIGH is null and LOW is null. А после minus какое условие в таком случае писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже селект из вашего первого вопроса, только модифицированный с использованием функции `nvl`.

`nvl` в качестве аргументов принимает 2 значения, первое это проверяемое значение(обычно поле, но можно и функцию вставить), второе возвращаемое значение, если первое оказалось `NULL`.

В примере ниже, `nvl(high, 0)` - если поле `high` будет `null`, вернется 0.

Так же можно передавать в качестве второго параметра поля и функции.

```
select id from high_and_low
group by id
having sum(nvl(high, 0)) + sum(nvl(low, 0)) = 0
```

Для строк можно попробовать преобразовать null к такому значению, которого гарантированно нет в полях и сравнивать с объединением значений:

```
select id from high_and_low
group by id
having nvl(high, 'NullValue') || nvl(low, 'NullValue') = 'NullValueNullValue'
```

Comment: Попробовал код. Выполнялся долго (100к записей), в итоге выдал ошибку ORA-01722: неверное число
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.   Я проверил типы полей - HIGH и LOW это VARCHAR2. Может быть в этом дело?

Comment: Ну тогда да, в этом дело. Видимо у вас там в таблице есть значения, которые нельзя сконвертировать в число. выполните команду `select distinct high from table` и  `select distinct low from table` и посмотрите, какие еще значения встречаются в таблице. P.S. измените вопрос, укажите, что `1` это строка `'1'`

Comment: В общем там NULL, числовые значения как строки, т.е. "1", "224", а также есть прям текст вида "помещение 1" или "ОФИС". Но нужно вычленить только NULL

Comment: Обновил ответ. Странно, у вас тогда этот скрипт не должен был работать по вашему первому посту, если таблица одна и та же.

Comment: При таком запросе ругается ( ORA-00979: выражение не является выражением GROUP BY
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Попробуйте заменить + на ||

Comment: К сожалению, аналогично. Та же ошибка с ||

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вариант с minus заменив условия на i`s not` null или `nvl(high, 'nil') = 'nil'`. Парадокс, но `nvl() = ''` работает быстрее чем `field is not null`